# Is there a local bus from Rinku Town (Osaka) or thereabouts to Yao Station or thereabouts?

Tags: japan, buses, osaka

I would like to travel from Rinku Town or Izumisano (Osaka) to Yao Station (Osaka) by local bus. Nearby departure and arrival locations are also of interest, it doesn't have to be perfectly from spot to spot.

Does anyone know if it is possible and how much it would cost?

Comment: Why use bus when Japan in general has excellent train system? A quick Google Maps search return at least 4 train-lines to travel between these stations. From 890 to 1400 Yen (8 to 12$)

Comment: The question is about taking the bus though. You don't need to question the question itself because the OP is valid. Kindly just answer questions that you actually know the answer too and not another question that you come up with yourself. *Sorry, just noticed that admin had edited the question so it differed from my OP. Reversed the change*

Comment: It certainly can't be done without transfers since the two areas are served by different bus companies (Nankai and Kintetsu respectively).

Comment: @Vesa This site gets a lot of naive questions from travel newbies.  If you're not one and are intentionally asking an unusual question, it's good to give a little background why.

Answer (score 3):

The Yahoo Japan navigation smartphone application does not find any local bus route between Izumisano or Rinku Town station on the one end and JR or Kintetsu Yao station on the other end, so such a route probably does not exist, or if it does, will be highly convoluted.